# Java NullPointerException in agent based model

Tags: java

I am using the MASON library to run a simple agent-based model.

As per specifications, I meant to access an agent's inspector by double-clicking on such agent in the Portrayal.

However, when I do so I get the following console error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sim.display.Display2D.createInspectors(Display2D.java:1737)
    at sim.display.Display2D$8.mouseClicked(Display2D.java:1392)
```

I went to Display2D.java:1737 to find:

```
 public void createInspectors( final Rectangle2D.Double rect, final GUIState simulation )
        {
        Bag inspectors = new Bag();
        Bag names = new Bag();

        Bag[] hitObjects = objectsHitBy(rect);
        for(int x=0;x<hitObjects.length;x++)
            {
            FieldPortrayal2DHolder p = (FieldPortrayal2DHolder)(portrayals.get(x));
            for( int i = 0 ; i < hitObjects[x].numObjs ; i++ )
                {
                LocationWrapper wrapper = (LocationWrapper) (hitObjects[x].objs[i]);
                inspectors.add(p.portrayal.getInspector(wrapper,simulation));
                names.add(p.portrayal.getName(wrapper));
                }
            }
        simulation.controller.setInspectors(inspectors,names); //1737
        }
```

However, this is a library file so I'm not familiar with it.

Any advice?

Library: cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/

Update:

Ok, it gets interesting...

I did an echo on the toString method of inspectors and names, returning:

```
insepectors sim.util.Bag@1b2202a names sim.util.Bag@16b334d
```

Ok so they're bags, a type of collection. Time to get their sizes...

```
insepectors 1 names 1
```

Good, they're not empty.

Let's follow the error stack

Next bit:

```
at sim.display.Display2D$8.mouseClicked(Display2D.java:1392)

// add mouse listener for the inspectors
        insideDisplay.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                if (handleMouseEvent(e)) { repaint(); return; }
                else
                    {
                    // we only care about mouse button 1.  Perhaps in the future we may eliminate some key modifiers as well
                    int modifiers = e.getModifiers();
                    if ((modifiers & e.BUTTON1_MASK) == e.BUTTON1_MASK)
                        {
                        final Point point = e.getPoint();
                        if( e.getClickCount() == 2 )
                           1392-> createInspectors( new Rectangle2D.Double( point.x, point.y, 1, 1 ),
                                Display2D.this.simulation );
                        if (e.getClickCount() == 1 || e.getClickCount() == 2)  // in both situations
                            performSelection( new Rectangle2D.Double( point.x, point.y, 1, 1 ));
                        repaint();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Ok, the error is clearly in the CreateInspectors method:

```
public void createInspectors( final Rectangle2D.Double rect, final GUIState simulation )
        {
        Bag inspectors = new Bag();
        Bag names = new Bag();

        Bag[] hitObjects = objectsHitBy(rect);
        for(int x=0;x<hitObjects.length;x++)
            {
            FieldPortrayal2DHolder p = (FieldPortrayal2DHolder)(portrayals.get(x));
            for( int i = 0 ; i < hitObjects[x].numObjs ; i++ )
                {
                LocationWrapper wrapper = (LocationWrapper) (hitObjects[x].objs[i]);
                inspectors.add(p.portrayal.getInspector(wrapper,simulation));
                names.add(p.portrayal.getName(wrapper));
                }
            }
        System.out.println("insepectors " + inspectors.size() + " names " + names.size());
        simulation.controller.setInspectors(inspectors,names);
        }
```

First thing I do:

```
System.out.println(rect.getCenterX() + " " + rect.getCenterY());
```

Which gives me 646.5 659.5. Seem to make sense as coordinates.

So next thing I want to look at hitObjects:

```
 System.out.println(hitObjects.length);
```

Returns 2. So I had two agents at that coordinates.

I assume the NPE is somewhere here:

```
for(int x=0;x<hitObjects.length;x++)
            {
            FieldPortrayal2DHolder p = (FieldPortrayal2DHolder)(portrayals.get(x));
            for( int i = 0 ; i < hitObjects[x].numObjs ; i++ )
                {
                LocationWrapper wrapper = (LocationWrapper) (hitObjects[x].objs[i]);
                inspectors.add(p.portrayal.getInspector(wrapper,simulation));
                names.add(p.portrayal.getName(wrapper));
                }
            }
```

The outer loop looks fine, but I'm having issues with the inner one. Advice?

Comment: and which line is 1737?

Comment: have you tried running an older release?

Comment: So either `simulation` or `controller` is null; I'd start by figuring out which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually going to write how to reason through the library code given as far as you've come since you sound capable.

You found the code. That's a good start. You've also found the line that it's on:

```
 simulation.controller.setInspectors(inspectors,names); //1737
```

And given what you know about NPEs you can reason that `simulation` or `controller` is `null`.

Do you know which? Can you reason about your code which you may have failed to set, or passed incorrectly? Can you put a debugger breakpoint or simple `println` statements in your code to determine which?

If not and you're using an IDE (you probably are), then from the source you just opened up, put a breakpoint before line 1737. When that line is reached, use the debugger to inspect the variable `simulation` then `simulation.controller` to see which is `null`. Exactly how to do this will depend on your IDE but it shouldn't be hard to find [using XKCD's tech support cheat sheet](https://xkcd.com/627/).

Then you will probably know the cause. If not, continue reading source code, e.g. look a level up to line 1737.

Comment: @max0005 you still haven't answered whether simulation or controller is null.

Comment: @djechilin for the simulation object I get sim.app.abmmodel.CancerSimulatorWithUI@628dee with the toString method, when I add the controller, so trying to echo   System.out.println(simulation.controller.toString()+"*"); I get NPE so I guess I'm having issues with the controller?

Comment: Yes, controller is null

Comment: Oh, looking back it appears I had forgotten a call to a parent constructor when creating the controller object in the GUI, that's probably why it was null. Thank you for you rhelp :D